# Is there anyway to download linux commands from a distro's repositatory into a usb stick?

Tags: linux, command-line, usb-flash-drive, download, repository

Recently, we bought a motherboard that requires everything to be the ABSOLUTE latest OS, drivers, etc or it won't run. However, we figured out how to force it into Legacy Mode to install an old Linux OS, but now its Ethernet port won't work. I need to install few simple linux command like Sudo in my system from its repository but no internet connection. So, is there a way I can download like say sudo command from another Linux OS's repository into an USB stick. Then, take it over to my linux system and install it.

Comment: do you actually WANT this old linux OS or is it just for staging stuff to later install a modern one? I used to have an RALink Wifi USB adapter that I used to get wifi for laptops without ethernet because the Distros I used shipped a driver that would work with it. that would get me online enough to install the chipset drivers that would run the built-in wifi.

Comment: Why would you want commands from another Linux OS's repository? Why not use the packages from the distribution that you installed? What distro did you install? Which version? Please add it to your question.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I wish I could download packages and install them from the distribution that I installed, but I can't. The latest motherboard that I purchased will not go on the INTERNET. The Linux OS reports that there is no NETWORK COMPONENT to make any connection, when in fact I have a Ethernet Port. It just that it is not active.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes, it is a MUST that I use this old Linux OS on my newly built computer system.

Comment: You can download almost all packages for all distributions on an USB stick. You have downloaded the current Linux install (you have still not revealed which distro and version) on the USB stick. So you should also be able to download extra packages on the USB stick from the same distribution and version. If you would care to share that information, we might point you to the website where they may be downloaded to your USB stick and be installed via the USB stick.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to install drivers for your network interface on the motherboard without an internet connection, right?

Then this might help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/146425/how-can-i-install-and-download-drivers-without-internet

Comment: A link alone is not enough as an answer, you should add the essentials of the solution.